# Spring boot [Thymeleaf]: EL1008E: Property or field 'category' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.Optional'

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a relationship between two tables **product** and **product category**. Now i want to Edit product.

I created a list, which when i click edit open another interface with product details plus Product category as an drop down, but i get an error on thymeleaf th:selected as i want it to display the drop down with the selected item in it, but i get error

*EL1008E: Property or field 'category' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.Optional'*

Please help to resolve

I tried to change the select to input it works fine

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" th:field="<b>${update.category.ProductCategoryID}"</b> />
```

but using selected dont work

```
<select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
    <option 
        th:each="prodCat : ${prodCatList}" 
        th:value="${prodCat.ProductCategoryID}" 
        th:text="${prodCat.CategoryName}"                            
        th:selected="${prodCat.ProductCategoryID} =={update.category.ProductCategoryID}">
    </option>
</select>
```

Below is the code snip

```
<form th:object="${update}" th:action="@{/product/save}" method="post">
  <div id="myForm">
....
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" th:field="${update.category.ProductCategoryID}" /> 
<select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
    <option 
        th:each="prodCat : ${prodCatList}" 
        th:value="${prodCat.ProductCategoryID}" 
        th:text="${prodCat.CategoryName}"
        th:selected="${prodCat.ProductCategoryID} == ${update.category.ProductCategoryID}" <-- problem
        >
    </option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ProdID" name="ProdID" th:field="${update.category.CategoryName}" />
```

Comment: Update seams to be of type Optional. Can you show the code where you load the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Update is Optional and not an object, and the view received the Öptional rather than Update directly.

```
//something like this needs to be done when updating the model for this attribute
Optional<Update> update = <your code to get this in Java>
update.ifPresent(foundUpdateObject -> model.addAttribute("update", foundUpdateObject))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks TechFree.

It work, I was doing a mistake where I am not taking the object from the Optional Class

Here is the code i put and it worked.

```
@GetMapping("/edit/{pctid}")
public String findOne(
            @PathVariable(value = "pctid") Integer pctid,
        Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("prodCatList", productCategoryRepo.findAll());

   productRepo.findById(pctid).ifPresent(o -> model.addAttribute("update", o));
//      model.addAttribute("update",productRepo.findById(pctid));
        return "/prod/edit";

    }
```